# Document_root на папку /home/username/srv упорно выдает 403 ошибку. Что делаю не так?

Tags: linux, apache, веб-программирование

Взял ssd vds поиграться, скриптики свои выложить.
Установил стек LAMP, перемещаю для удобства document_root из папки /var/www/ в /home/username/srv/
Упорно выдает 403 ошибку.

Лезу в гугл, пишут - дай права на папку /srv пользователю www-data. Делаю по-другому - добавляю пользователя www-data в группу username. Выходит, что теперь на пользователя распространяются права группы владельца папки, а именно - вторая цифра в правах доступа. А права у меня на папку 775.

Дальше - больше. Выставляю права 777 на все папки как вниз по дереву, так и вверх. Тот же результат.
Добавляю пользователя www-data в группу root. Опять 403 ошибка.

Проверил, от кого апач запускает процесс - www-data, все правильно.
Куда копать - ума не приложу.

Выкладываю конфигурационный файл

```
GNU nano 2.2.6  File: /etc/apache2/sites-available/musaevhs.ru.conf           

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName musaevhs.ru

    ServerAdmin [email]musaev.haybulla@gmail.com[/email]
    DocumentRoot /home/musaevhs/srv/public_html/

    <Directory /home/musaevhs/srv/public_html>
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Есть мысли, что я упустил?

Answer (score 1):

Добавь DirectoryIndex.
Добавь вырезку из error лога.
Добавь результат работы ls -lah /home/musaevhs/srv и public_html.

Права для директорий должны быть 755, а для файлов 644. Владельцем файлов и папок должен быть www-data.
Еще выложи выполнение команды ps -ef|grep apache если debian и ps -ef|grep httpd если rhel.

Убери www-data из группы root.

Вместо require all granted пропиши:

```
order allow,deny
allow all
```

И как в httpd.conf инклудишь sites-available?

Comment: `Владельцем файлов и папок должен быть www-data` - это еще зачем? Владельцем должен быть user, под которым будешь все выкладывать. Разрешать апачу запись можно только в том случае, если без этого никак (например, надо логи где-то писать, либо картинки куда-то загружать)

Comment: @BOPOH это все selinux или appamor смотря какой дистрибутив. Ну или узер извращенец раз в bsd пользуется nano.

Comment: Ну почему же сразу извращенец?..))) Новичок я, как в нете в инструкциях написано, так и пользую. А каким Вы какой редактор советуете?..

Comment: @MusaevHaybulla vi или vim. Проблему решили? Кстате с подачи BOPOH задумался о selinux/apparmor. Скорее всего вам надо их либо отключить либо подправить профиль apache.